# Let $S\subseteq V $ and $v\in V\setminus S$. Show that $S\cup \{v\}$ is l.d. $\iff v\in\langle S\rangle$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space, $S\subseteq V$ and $v\in V\setminus S$. Show that $S\cup \{v\}$ is linearly dependent if and only if $v\in\langle S\rangle$

So, can you help me evaluate my proof? Any observation will be appreciated. Thanks!

Dem:

$\Leftarrow)$

$v\in \langle S\rangle\implies S\cup \{v\}$ is linearly dependent.

We have that $v\in \langle S\rangle$. If $\color{OrangeRed}{v= 0}$, then $v$ can be expressed as a linear combination of elements of $S$:$$v=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_is_i=0,\text{for}\text{ }\alpha_i\in \Bbb K,\forall i=1,\dots ,n\text{ }\text{and}\text{ } s_1,\dots ,s_n\in S$$

So $S\cup \{v\}$ must satisfy the definition of linearly dependence. We see that:

$$\text{For}\text{ }s_1,\dots ,s_n,s_{n+1}\in S\cup\{v\},\exists \alpha_i\ne 0: \alpha_1s_1+\dots +\alpha_ns_s+\alpha_{n+1}\cdot 0= v$$
$$\implies S\cup\{v\}\text{ }\text{is linearly dependent}$$

Now, $v\in \langle S\rangle$ and $\color{OrangeRed}{v\ne 0}$:
$$v=\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_is_i, \text{for}\text{ }\alpha_i\in \Bbb K,\forall i=1,\dots ,n\text{ }\text{and}\text{ } s_1,\dots ,s_n\in S$$

Then: $-v+\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_is_i=0\rightarrow \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} \alpha_is_i=\alpha_1s_1+\dots +\alpha_ns_n+(-1)v=0$, wich shows that $S\cup\{v\}$ is linearly dependent.

$\Rightarrow)$

$S\cup \{v\}\text{ }\text{is linearly dependent}\implies v\in \langle S\rangle$

Let $S\cup \{v\}=\{s_1,\dots ,s_n,s_{n+1}=v\}$, and taking the hypothesis we get that:

For $s_i\in S$ and $\alpha_i\in \Bbb K$,(not all zero)  $\forall i=1,\dots ,n+1: \alpha_1s_1+\dots +\alpha_ns_n+\alpha_{n+1}s_{n+1}=0$

Let's suppose that $\color{OrangeRed}{\alpha_{n+1}\ne 0}$, and so we can get a linear combination of the vector $v=s_{n+1}$:
$$v=s_{n+1}=-\frac{1}{\alpha_{n+1}}\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_is_i$$

Therefore, $v\in \langle S\rangle$

Now, suppose that $\color{OrangeRed}{\alpha_{n+1}= 0}$, then the lineal combination becomes:
$$\alpha_1s_1+\dots +\alpha_ns_s+\alpha_{n+1}s_{n+1}=0$$
$$\alpha_1s_1+\dots +\alpha_ns_n=0$$

So we just found that $S$ is linearly dependent, wich is not defined as part of the hypothesis. So $\alpha_{n+1}$ must be non zero. And so $v\in \langle S\rangle$.

Comment: I think you've skipped something - how do you know that $\alpha_{n + 1} \ne 0$? In fact, I think you can't deduce that from what you've got - you need to assume something like "$S$ is linearly independent" in your question. If the question is asking you whether this equivalence holds, you might try looking for a counterexample.

Comment: @Roma_Rayado. I’m not sure you appreciated the strength of Izaak’s comment. If $S=\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(1,1,0)\}$ and $v=(0,0,1)$ then $S\cup\{v\}$ is l.d. but $v\not\in \langle S \rangle$. Just because $S$ is not required to be l.d. doesn’t mean it isn’t.

Comment: Your argument  for the $v=0$ case feels weird. If $v=0$, then $S\cup \{v\}$ is going to be linearly dependent but $v$ is also always in $\langle S \rangle$, and both of these follow more less from the definitions

Comment: @Izaak van Dongen.  Can't see why, nad I remember I thought something about considering the linear independece for $\langle S\rangle$, can you elaborate a little bit on this?

Comment: In your $\Leftarrow$ demonstration, there is no need for a special case for $v = 0$. Everything you did for $v \ne 0$ is true for $v = 0$ as well. As for Izaak's comment: If $S$ is linearly dependent by itself, then every set $T$ with $S \subset T$ will also be linearly dependent. This includes $S\cup \{v\}$, regardless of whether $v \in S$ or not.